# Regexp to match text in equations but ignoring Latex commands

Tags: regex, string, latex

I am trying to match anything in math equations but ignoring Latex commands. I have come up with the following expression so far:

```
(?<!\\)\b([a-zA-Z0-9.,]+)
```

The string I have:

```
200\% Depreciation\ (Year_2) = $610,500\times\frac{blah}{12}\times0.2
```

But my expression does not match `0.2` near the end and it doesn't match `2` in `Year_2`. I have other complex equations with similar problems.

The problem I believe is the word boundary `\b` but I don't have any better alternative. Unfortunately, I found out I can't use quantifiers inside negative lookbehind. So I couldn't do

```
(?<!\\[a-z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9.,]+)
```

Basically I want to match all of the following:

- numbers (including `$`, `%`, `,`, `.`)
- sentences, words, characters, even spaces

while ignoring Latex commands in the form `\foo` and special characters such as `^`, `_`, `=`, `+`, `-` and brackets.

A perfect expression will match:

`200\% Depreciation\`(`Year`_`2`) = `$610,500`\times\frac{`blah`}{`12`}\times`0.2`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm confused about your string.  If the backslashes be _literal_, then is the `%` in `200\%` not part of the number `200`?  Alternatively, if the backslashes are _not_ literal, then is `\t` a tab character?

Comment: I believe it is bug in Mathjax so I have to escape `%` to display it properly. Other characters are not escaped. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Maybe @Wiktor can help you here; I know too little about LaTex syntax to guess at a regex.

Comment: Could you tell us the expected matches, please?

Comment: It doesn't match `0.2` because there're no word boundaries before; same explanation for `2`, the character before `_` **is** a word character.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the expected matches. Sorry for the delay. @NorbertIncze

Comment: How about `\\[a-z]+(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-zA-Z0-9.,$% ]+`?

Comment: This works!! ... I will test it thoroughly and get back. Thanks!! @Toto

Comment: Don't know what was I thinking but I assumed it is you without looking at the profile. I am actually using your expression in my work and it's working well. I wish I could mark your comment as answer. @Toto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194708/discussion-between-erfan-and-toto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
\\[a-z]+(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-zA-Z0-9.,$% ]+
```

**Explanation:**

```
\\[a-z]+            # a backslash followed by 1 or more alpha
(*SKIP)(*F)         # skip & forget previous match
|                   # OR
[a-zA-Z0-9.,$% ]+   # 1 or more any of these characters.
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bvVCU9/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

`(?<!\\)(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+\\?|\$?[0-9]{1,3}(\,?[0-9]{1,3})*(\.[0-9]+)?(\\[%])?`

It is a bit longer, because it checks if the number has a correct form or not.

[See explanation on regex101...](https://regex101.com/r/jsnfIY/1)